# Hive remove duplicate type of relationship

Tags: sql, hive

I am a new SQL user and I need your help! I am doing a relational graph analysis based on a SQL database, which is the only resource I can utilize and having trouble **keeping distinct type of relationship between two people**.

I have this table:

```
+---------+----------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
| left_id | left_rel       | common | right_rel      | right_id  |
+---------+----------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
| Tom     | graduated_from | MIT    | worked_in      | Jerry     |
| Tom     | graduated_from | MIT    | graduated_from | Lee       |
| Lee     | graduated_from | MIT    | graduated_from | Tom       |
| Tom     | graduated_from | MIT    | graduated_from | Jerry     |
+---------+----------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
```

I want a table where identical relationships between two people are reduced to one single relationship. So, the relationship that Tom and Lee both graduated from MIT has two records, I want to drop those duplicates. I can accept to have Tom as either Left_id or Right_id, **only if his id and rel mapped**.

Hope this piece of create table code save you some time.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
      left_id varchar(20)
    , left_rel varchar(50)
    , common varchar(50)
    , right_rel varchar(50)
    , right_id varchar(20)
);
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ("Tom", "graduated_from", "MIT", "worked_in", "Jerry");
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ("Tom", "graduated_from", "MIT", "graduated_from", "Lee");
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ("Lee", "graduated_from", "MIT", "graduated_from", "Tom");
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ("Tom", "graduated_from", "MIT", "graduated_from", "Jerry");
```

What I have tried so far

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1
AS 
SELECT 
        greatest(CONCAT_WS(':', left_id, left_rel), CONCAT_WS(':', right_id, right_rel)) AS Left_Part
      , Common
      , least(CONCAT_WS(':', left_id, left_rel), CONCAT_WS(':', right_id, right_rel)) AS Right_Part
  FROM tmp
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp2
AS 
SELECT 
        T1.Left_Part
      , T1.Common
      , T1.Right_Part
  FROM ( SELECT 
                 *
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(DISTRIBUTE BY Left_Part, Right_Part) AS rn
           FROM tmp1
        ) T1
 WHERE T1.rn = 1
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE result
AS 
SELECT 
        SPLIT(Left_Part,':')[0] as left_id
      , SPLIT(Left_Part,':')[1] as left_rel
      , Common
      , SPLIT(Right_Part,':')[0] as right_id
      , SPLIT(Right_Part,':')[1] as right_rel
  FROM tmp2
;
```

gives result

```
+---------+----------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
| left_id | left_rel       | common | right_rel      | right_id  |
+---------+----------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
| Tom     | graduated_from | MIT    | worked_in      | Jerry     |
| Tom     | graduated_from | MIT    | graduated_from | Lee       |
| Tom     | graduated_from | MIT    | graduated_from | Jerry     |
+---------+----------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi @misterlear please can you show us what have you tried already? Also please show us the data you expect to get from this data that you have and that you shown us alerad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need:

Common

```
id  name
1   MIT
```

RelationType

```
id rel_type
1  graduated_from 
2  worked_in
```

Person

```
id  name
1   Tom
2   Lee
3   Jerry
```

Relation

```
TypeId  PersonId CommonId
1       1        1
2       1        1
3       2        1
```

The data is retrieving by

```
SELECT p1.name, rt1.rel_type, c.name, rt2.rel_type, p2.name
FROM Relation r1
JOIN Relation r2 ON r1.CommonId = r2.CommonId 
                AND r1.PersonId != r2.PersonId  -- or maybe '<'
JOIN Common c ON r1.CommonId = c.id
JOIN RelationType rt1 ON r1.TypeId = rt1.id
JOIN RelationType rt2 ON r2.TypeId = rt2.id
JOIN Person p1 ON r1.PersonId = p1.id
JOIN Person p1 ON r2.PersonId = p2.id
```